# MySQL выборка елементов

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно выбрать `product_id`, для которого `filter_id` одновременно равен например `1` и `5`.

Как это сделать? Спасибо

Answer (score -2):

```
select product_id from table where filter_id = 1 and filter_id = 5 group by product_id
```

Comment: Неверно. Просили одновременно, а у тебя получилось или.